# Add a counter to If statement

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, count

I want to count the number of patient visits to a particular clinic and log them.

For example, a patient with hypertension is advised to take two blood pressure readings over a year, and each visit a patient makes to the clinic is added to a new row in our database.

| Visit | BP reading | Blood sugar reading |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 Jan 2022 | 120/80 | 6.5 |
| 3 Mar 2022 | Nil | 6.7 |

I have come up with the following code to check if the patient has fulfilled the two visits/readings for the year:

```vb
If CDR.Cells(j + offset, "H").Value = IC And CDR.Cells(j + offset, "X").Value = 1 Then
    missingCheck = 0
    '1) Two blood pressure
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(CVD.Range("M10", "M" & LastRowCVD), "<>" & "", CVD.Range("N10", "N" & LastRowCVD), "<>" & "", CVD.Range("F10", "F" & LastRowCVD), IC) < 2 Then
        If missingCheck = 0 Then
            missingCheck = 1
            pastesht.Cells(pasterownum, "L").Value = "Missing: 2 BP"
        Else
            pastesht.Cells(pasterownum, "L").Value = pastesht.Cells(pasterownum, "L").Value & ", 2 BP"
        End If
        If IsEmpty(pastesht.Cells(pasterownum, "J").Value) Then
            pastesht.Cells(pasterownum, "J").Value = "2 BP"
        Else
            pastesht.Cells(pasterownum, "J").Value = pastesht.Cells(pasterownum, "J").Value & ", 2 BP"
        End If
    End If
```

In the above case, the code will tell me that the patient is missing two readings for blood pressure.

Is it possible to add a counter into the 'If' statement which counts the number of visits/readings each patient has made and indicate how many visits/readings they are missing?
For example: '1 bp reading left', instead of a 2 or nothing counter as per what I have.

Comment: Why vba? countifs() could do this based on the patient ID etc

Comment: Your code doesn't tell what are all these variables and ranges for. Also, when is this cell `pastesht.Cells(pasterownum, "J")` empty? and what does it refer to?

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing what you are asking is to put the result of the `COUNTIFS` function in a varaible, and write in your desired cell how many reading are left.

```
Dim BPreadings as Integer
BPreadings  = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs( _
                        CVD.Range("M10", "M" & LastRowCVD), "<>" & "", _
                        CVD.Range("N10", "N" & LastRowCVD), "<>" & "", _
                        CVD.Range("F10", "F" & LastRowCVD), IC)
If BPreadings < 2 Then
    pastesht.Cells(pasterownum, "L").Value = "Missing: " & 2 - BPreadings & " BP"
End If
```

I don't understand the rest of your code, so I can't incorporate it into mine. But I hope you get the general idea.